# Angular router blocks calls to server

Tags: angular, angular-router

Here's my router code:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: IndexComponent},
    { path: 'microservice/:id', component: MicroserviceComponent}
];
```

I'm trying to load an endpoint from the server by loading a URL (Get request) like this

```
window.open("localhost:8080/api/login", "_self");
```

However, if I do this in main page (path `''`), it gets to the server and I can see it from the server side. If I run this code in `microservice/bluh` page, then the main page is displayed and the login endpoint is not hit.

Is there something wrong with the routing that prevents the call from making to the server?

Comment: Where are you doing the call from? Are you subscribing to router events and then doing the call?

Comment: @xyz I'm doing the call in another component called `nagivation`. It always exists and I'm just switching that IndexComponent and MicroserviceComponent. There's a button on the navigation component UI that links to a function where the call is made

Comment: So you are saying that you are basically making the call on a button click, it works if you are on `Index` and doesn't if you are on `microservice`?

Comment: @xyz correct ....

Comment: Can you try with the protocol? like: `window.open("http://localhost:8080/api/login", "_self");` or `location.href="http://localhost:8080/api/login"`

Comment: @xyz Tried. None of the above works in the microservice component but all works in the index component...

Comment: What is the url under which the "angular app" is being served (not the api, the angular client app code)? Is it the same http://localhost:8080 ?

Comment: @JudeRaj Yes....

Comment: You can use IndexComponent instead of MicroserviceComponent in your router config, this can determine the problem occurs in Router or MicroserviceComponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add pathMatch: 'full'  to your main component:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: IndexComponent,pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'microservice/:id', component: MicroserviceComponent}
];
```